# the use of curly brackets in node.js

Tags: node.js

**Q1:**

I understand

`const { headers, method, url } = request;` is object destructuring.

But I can't find the explanation for this usage:

`const responseBody = { method, URL, body }`

It will return:

`{ method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  body: '' }`

It seems I can just pass the value of the key-value pair?

Is there any reference or explanation for this?

**Q2:**

Also, I saw this

`_readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },`

as I parsing the HTTP request, and I don't know what are
***ReadableSate*** and ***BufferList***.

They are both the member of the value of the key-value pair,
but what are they? are there terms describing them? or what types are they?

thx!

Comment: `const responseBody = { method, url, body }` is the equivalent to `const responseBody = { "method": method, "url" : url, "body": body }`

Comment: @Seblor is there any reference, document, or tutorial introducing this?

Comment: Yes. This notation has been introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: To answer your second question, `_readableState` is an object which class is `ReadableState`, which has a property named `buffer` which class is `BufferList`.

Comment: These are 2 unrelated questions. Consider asking them separately next time. The first one isn't specific to Node in any way and has been answered numerous times on SO.

Comment: @estus ok, I'll be more careful asking question next time. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const responseBody = { method, URL, body }
```

Shorthand property names were introduced in ES2015: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/pull/1214

The example in your second questions uses TypeScript notation where the type of variables is specified.